# Windows' Remote Desktop Connection through WAN -- easiest way?

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop

What's the easiest way to connect to a computer through WAN (i.e its IP address instead of its local computer name) using Windows' RDP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type in its IP address (`a.b.c.d`) or FQDN (`foo.bar.baz.com`) instead of a Windows Networking name (`\\foo`).

Comment: I access all the computers on my domain through their FQDN (fully qualified domain name) - for example: `windows7.jaredharley.com`

Comment: you mean it still works the same way?  oh good!  i haven't used it since before Vista was a gleam in Microsoft's eye...

Comment: What port does RDP listen to?

Comment: port 3389 by default